# Option Select + SQL/PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

Estoy con la siguiente situación la cual no he sabido aun como resolver, espero me pueda dar alguna idea o ayudar, por favor.

Tengo una base de datos en SQL Server la cual ocupo para llenar cada option select, dependiendo las opciones que yo ingrese es la información que me mostrara en una tabla dinámica; el problema me surge cuando alguno de los option se selecciona el apartado de TODOS ya que aun no he sabido como consultarlo con la base.

Los apartados que tiene cada select son los siguientes:

- Comedor: TODOS, EMPLEADOS, SINDICALIZADO
- Tipo comida: TODOS, DESAYUNO, COMIDA
- Empleados: TODOS, Muestra el nombre de cada persona.

Si se selecciona TODOS en algún campo, el valor que devuelven al hacer clic en consultar es 0.

Forzosamente deberán seleccionar la fecha que desean consultar, por lo cual dependiendo la combinación que se haga debe darme el resultado solicitado, ejemplo:

- Comedor: TODOS
- Tipo comida: DESAYUNO
- Empleados: EDGAR

En la imagen muestro un ejercicio de como se ve lo que yo seleccione sin el TODOS, la problematica que me surge es como el ejemplo qué pongo, cuando en un solo select selecciono la opción de TODOS o bien, si en los tres pongo esa misma opción ¿Cómo puedo obtener los resultados seleccionados?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="mydatatable-container" style="width:1080px;">
        <table class="records_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="mydatatable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="encabezadoTabla">
                    <th style="width:300px;">Empleado</th>
                    <th style="width:150px;">No. Empleado</th>
                    <th style="width:150px;">Fecha</th>
                    <th style="width:100px;">Hora</th>
                    <th>No. Contador</th>
                    <th>Comedor</th>
                    <th style="width:200px;">Tipo Comida</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <div id="">
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['input_consultar'])) {
                        if ($_POST['input_fecha_inicial'] != '') {
                            $sql_consultar = "SELECT fecha, hora, emp_code, nombre, contador, terminal_id, tipo_comida FROM tabla_comedor 
                            WHERE 
                           tipo_comida = '" . $_POST['input_comida'] . "' AND 
                           terminal_id = '" . $_POST['input_comedor'] . "' AND 
                           nombre = '" . $_POST['input_empleados'] . "' AND 
                           fecha >= '" . $_POST['input_fecha_inicial'] . "' AND fecha <= '" . $_POST['input_fecha_final'] . "' ORDER BY contador DESC";
                            $res_consultar = sqlsrv_query($conn_B, $sql_consultar);
                            if (!$res_consultar) { ?>
                                <?php } else {
                                while ($row_consultar = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res_consultar)) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?= $row_consultar['nombre']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $row_consultar['emp_code']; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                            $date = $row_consultar['fecha']->format('d-m-Y');
                                            echo $date;
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                            $time = $row_consultar['hora']->format('H:i:s');
                                            echo $time;
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><?= $row_consultar['contador']; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                            if ($row_consultar['terminal_id']) {
                                                echo "Empleados";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "Sindicalizado";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                            if ($row_consultar['tipo_comida'] == '0') {
                                                echo "Desayuno";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "Comida";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, incluye en la pregunta 1) el motor de base de datos, hay muchos fabricantes de bases de datos SQL (SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, y muchos más). 2) Un ejemplo de los valores que hay en los select del formulario. Es importante ver qué valor toman cuando se elige _todos_.

Comment: @jachguate por las funciones del controlador `sqlsrv_query` se adivina que es SQL Server, aunque como dices, conviene que quien pregunta facilite las cosas lo más posible sin tener que obligarnos a adivinar. Dicho eso, la pregunta es algo confusa. Si entendí bien, cuando se seleccione `todos` hay que buscar todos los registros ¿? En ese caso, determina si se seleccionó todos y haz un `SELECT * FROM ...` sin criterio `WHERE`. ¿O bien `todos` significa filtrar por todos los campos, o sea, agregar un `WHERE` por cada campo?

Comment: @A.Cedano insisto mucho en el tema de las etiquetas, pues es la manera en que se organiza el sitio. Y 2, supongo que si, es la opción (a) que planteas, y que al seleccionar todos en algún _select_ habrá que ir eliminando partes del _where_ hasta que probablemente no quede nada, si selecciona _todos_ en todos los _selects_.

Comment: @jachguate no había pensado también en la utilidad de las etiquetas para organizar el sitio, así que mayor razón tienes. En cuanto a la pregunta es totalmente confusa para mi: *¿qué puedo hacer si en cada option hay diferentes combinaciones con el apartado de TODOS?* No entiendo cómo en cada option pueda haber **diferentes combinaciones con el apartado de TODOS**.

Comment: Les agradezco mucho su tiempo, ya actualice la información espero a ver sido más clara con lo que estoy intentando hacer. @A.Cedano

Comment: El valor que toma cuando se elige la opción TODOS es 0. Gracias por tu tiempo @jachguate

Comment: Bueno, ahora está un poquito más claro, pero seguimos intentando adivinar la lógica. Pregunto: ¿Cómo debería ser la consulta si en los tres option se selecciona `TODOS`? ¿Cómo debería ser si en uno de los option se selecciona `TODOS` y en los otros se selecciona otra cosa? Según mi lógica, debes eliminar del criterio `WHERE` aquellos elementos en los que se seleccionó `TODOS`, puesto que se quieren todas las filas de esos elementos.

Comment: La consulta que hasta ahorita tengo es  la que anexo en el código de arriba, pero como bien me lo comentas, el criterio de TODOS aún no se cómo agregarlo ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Espero haberte entendido, agrega el case de cada una de las condiciones, algo asi como

```
Select fecha
     , hora
     , emp_code
     , nombre
     , contador
     , terminal_id
     , tipo_comida 
FROM tabla_comedor
WHERE tipo_comida = (CASE WHEN tipo_comida = 'TODOS' THEN tipo_comida ELSE @tipo_comida)
```

Te pongo el ejemplo en SQL ya solo adaptarlo con PHP

Quedo al pendiente Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, implementado con los select si el tipo de comida da 0 pero ese criterio no lo tengo en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto. Dado que estás usando un lenguaje como PHP, mi sugerencia sería algo en la línea de ir añadiendo o no añadiendo las condiciones a la cláusula where en la cadena dónde se va armando la consulta dependiendo de si el usuario ha seleccionado un valor o el valor para *todos*.

Esto, porque si quiero ver todos los tipos de comida, en realidad la consulta no debiera llevar una condición de ningún tipo con el campo `tipo_comida` en la cláusula where.

La lógica para armar la parte de una condición particular iría algo así:

```php
  if ($_POST['input_comedor'] != 0) {
    $cond = "and terminal_id = '".$_POST['input_comedor']."'";
  } else
    $cond = "";
  }
```

Es decir, si hay un valor con el cual comparar, se devuelve esa parte, y si no, una cadena vacía. Estas *partes* se irían concatenando para formar la cláusula where que finalmente se le va a enviar a la base de datos.

Valiéndonos del operador ternario, podríamos resumir la misma lógica en:

```php
  $cond = $_POST['input_comedor'] != 0 ? "and terminal_id = '".$_POST['input_comedor']."'" : "";
```

Lo siguiente que habría que hacer es cambiar el orden de las condiciones de la cláusula `where` para que aparezcan primero las condiciones *fijas*, como el rango de fechas, y después las condiciones que pueden o no ir.  Esto nos permite *simplificar* la lógica, pues las condiciones que pueden ir o no siempre van a comenzar con el operador lógico `and`.

Una vez comprendida la idea, no necesitamos realmente variables auxiliares, pues podemos ir concatenando todo de una vez en la cadena de la sentencia select completa:

```php
  $sql_consultar = ""
    ."SELECT fecha, hora, emp_code, nombre, contador, terminal_id, tipo_comida "
    ."  FROM tabla_comedor "
    ." WHERE fecha between '".$_POST['input_fecha_inicial']."' AND '".$_POST['input_fecha_final']."' "
    .$_POST['input_comida'] != 0    ? " AND tipo_comida = '".$_POST['input_comida']."' " : ""
    .$_POST['input_comedor'] != 0   ? " AND terminal_id = '".$_POST['input_comedor']."' " : ""
    .$_POST['input_empleados'] != 0 ? " AND nombre = '".$_POST['input_empleados']."' " : ""
    ."   ORDER BY contador DESC";
  $res_consultar = sqlsrv_query($conn_B, $sql_consultar);
```

Debes asegurarte que esto produzca una sentencia SQL válida. Yo he intentado con mis mejores habilidades, pero he escrito el código directamente en la respuesta y no tengo los medios para probarlo ahora mismo.  Si has comprendido la idea, confío también en que podrás corregir algún error que se me haya colado. Si no, pues, dejame un comentario y lo vemos con gusto.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jachguate ya lo trate de implementar en lo que tengo pero la lógica es lo que aún no logro adaptar con la consulta.

Comment: Qué dificultad estás teniendo?

Comment: Disculpa la demora, ya quedó solo estoy teniendo problemas con meterlo a la tabla dinámica, es decir, que me muestre lo que seleccione.

Comment: Bueno, "estoy teniendo problemas" no es la descripción más detallada que he escuchado de un problema y, me temo que no es posible ayudarte con esa descripción de tus problemas.